# Firefox: Signed script shows scary certificate dialog

Tags: javascript, firefox, certificate

The context: I'm writing JavaScript to run an executable and tweak some registry entries on the client machine.  I've signed the .JAR using SignTool and my company's Authenticode certificate, but running the script produces a dialog saying:

[image: scary certificate dialog]

There is no mention of the root certificate authority (in this case Comodo, I believe), so I could just as well have generated a self-signed certificate to put the company name string in the dialog.

My question is: is this all the user is meant to see? This example page at `jar:http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-script-demo.jar!/signed-script-demo.html` shows the same dialog, but there's still a lack of any "examine this certificate" link or mention of a root CA.

Are there any recent resources for writing signed scripts?  The mozilla pages are mostly several years old and many reference now-defunct documentation at developer.netscape.com.

-- Martin

Answer (score 2):

The code that runs those signed jars and elevates privileges hasn't changed in years either, so that documentation should be correct.  The code hasn't really been touched because nobody on the web uses that stuff.  Yes, I'm aware of the chicken-egg problem here with the crappy UI.

You could try filing a bug with Mozilla about this, but I'm not sure it'd get worked on (but patches would likely be welcomed).

Answer (score 2):

We were forced to use signed scripts to access our Firefox addon from JavaScript. I wrote my experience about it [here](https://github.com/alexkasko/firefox-signed-scripts).

Shortly:

- encapsulate your privileged logic in separate HTML+JS page
- make this page do actual work on page load
- sign it and put to server (you need packaging, custom content-type, etc.)
- on usual (unsigned) pages: load signed page into hidden IFRAME and interop with it using JavaScript callbacks

Comment: If you're putting the code in an addon, do you really need the signing stuff as well?  We ship a native code plugin (I admit I'm hazy on the distinction between an addon and a plugin) created with FireBreath, and plain old JavaScript can interact with its API without any signing.

Comment: @RichieHindle, maybe it depends on addon nature. Our addon uses NSS to access USB e-token device, without 'UniversalXPConnect' privilege it fails with 'Permission denied for  to get property XPCComponents.classes' on 'Components.classes['...'].createInstance(...)' JS call.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right.  Everything that our plugin does, it does directly with native code.  We're not trying to use any restricted pieces of Firefox from within the plugin.