# Signed script to do cross-domain queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read [this article](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) which said:

> Digitally sign your scripts. In Firefox you can apply a digital signature to your script and those scripts will then be considered "trusted" by the browser. Firefox will then let you make XMLHttpRequests to any domain

I read [this page](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html) to see how to accomplish this signed script, but it really didn't explain it all that well. Can someone show me how to go about signing my script?

Comment: What is your overall goal with this?

Comment: I'd like to access the NY TImes API (see [my earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478544/grabbing-data-from-new-york-times-api))

Comment: I believe Firefox has already discontinued use of UniversalBrowserRead and is planning to axe enablePrivilege altogether.

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate.

Comment: Read my answer in this post for how to query cross-domain:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147363/extracting-page-title-using-javascript/9147960#9147960
What specific problems are you having with the api?

Comment: I'm already familiar with YQL and use it in a number of scripts. The problem here is that I need to be able to input a nytimes article url and the script should return the headline, the byline, and the date of the article. I tried using the Symantic API (see [this example](http://prototype.nytimes.com/gst/apitool/index.html?api_id=15&request_id=2&article_uri=2010%2F10%2F06%2Fbusiness%2Fmedia%2F06tribune&fields=article_list&offset=&resp_format=json&perform_request=Make+Request&use_pp=on)). The JSON returned contains other related article. Somewhere within the JSON results is the entry I want.

Comment: continuing from previous post: do a `ctrl-f` for `At Flagging Tribune, Tales of a Bankrupt Culture`. That String appears in random locations in the results. If I could loop through the `results[index]` and check if that entry contains the url I inputted, then I could probably pull it off. However, the API doesn't support JSONP, so I'm trying to find alternatives. FWIW, I tried using YQL (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/3/)), but the text returned is really messy. It is the JSON text as a String and I can't use the JSON parsing capability.

Comment: In other words, the text returned by YQL is the JSON of the JSON. Is there a function to un-JSON a String? I guessing not built in to JQuery but could it be pulled off by writing a script to do that?

Comment: Maybe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9683754/314015) will help, it provides link to FF scripts signing instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This had been deprecated for years and was finally nuked in [Firefox 17](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bypassing_Security_Restrictions_and_Signing_Code).