# Un-JSON a String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a function to un-JSON a String? I guessing it wouldn't be built in to JQuery, but could it be pulled off by writing a script that manipulates the String? I'm encountering this in the following.

I'm using the NYTimes API, but it doesn't support JSONP, so I'm trying to find alternatives to access it. I can't use a server-side proxy by virtue of the circumstances this script will be run in. I am trying YQL [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/3/), but the text returned is really messy. It is the JSON text as a String, and I can't use the JSON parsing capability. In other words, the text returned by YQL is the JSON of the JSON.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491500/signed-script-to-do-cross-domain-queries) for more context.

Comment: `result` is JSON. You can parse it using `JSON.parse`: `var obj = JSON.parse(result);`. Then `obj.query.results.p` contains JSON again. You can parse it with `JSON.parse`: `var p = JSON.parse(obj.query.results.p);` and so on... if you have a string and it contains JSON, use `JSON.parse`. Always. If `JSON.parse` is not available, then include this library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: That's not working. See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/6/). It just returns `[object Object]`.

Comment: Yes, that's the default string representation of an object (which means it **does** work). What do you expect an object to look like? A better debugging method is `console.log`: http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/7/ (use Chrome, open the console). You are meant to access the properties of the object. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/8/

Comment: Can you write down an example of how the fake JSON looks like?

Comment: @ Felix Cool, thanks a lot! I'm kind of a JS novice.

Answer (score 2):

try using `JSON.parse()` method

Comment: I replied that, then deleted it because I read OP had written "I can't use the JSON parsing capability"... although I don't really understand why

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want JSON.parse, but you're looking for a jquery way, then you can use

```
$.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

Comment: This is the naive way, which is quite insecure. Consider `myJSONtext` to be altered by someone evil so that it is equal to `"alert('hacked')"`.